# Which kind of public sitemap should I build for a search based navigation site

Tags: seo, sitemap, directory

I have a search based navigation web-site. Each query has filters as well as sort-by. The search results point to end-pages inside the site. Each of those pages has many outlinks to other end-pages. Currently I have a XML sitemap which directs crawlers to all the end pages. I'm trying to add a silo sitemap directory to improve SEO. Assuming this is the right direction I have a couple of options:

1. end pages sorted alphabetically.
2. Pages by major search filters, and then divide alphabetically.
3. Pages for every filter and cross option between them and the sort-by.

Which would you recommend and why?

NOTE: I'm not referring to a XML sitemap.

Comment: Are you talking about how the URLs are sorted/grouped within the Sitemap itself?

Comment: Yes. As far as I understand this makes the pages reachable in low-depth and also helps gain more SEO by grouping the pages.

Answer (score 1):

None. The order in which URLs appear in a Sitemap, or how they're grouped, [doesn't have any known effect for SEO](http://www.sitemaps.org/faq.html#faq_url_position). It also doesn't affect public-facing site maps. The issue of link order on a page [is discussed in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6uRKvnrsnE) by Google engineer Matt Cutts.

Incidentally, [there's a convention that the S in XML Sitemap is capitalised](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184), which helps to avoid the sort of confusion we encountered in the comments.

Comment: I assume from your link my question wasn't clear. I wasn't referring to a XML sitemap. I was referring to a navigation-able that build a site directory that is able to reach most/all pages in several clicks, and also group them.

Comment: @Noam I asked if you were referring to the Sitemap; you said "yes" – can't be much clearer than that. In any case, same applies to public-facing site maps.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't quite sure if you're referring to an XML sitemap that you submit to Google via the Webmaster tools or a public sitemap that is included within your page.

For XML sitemaps, you can provide a `<priority></priority>` tag that you can denote certain pages to be given higher precedence for search engines to crawl.

Comment: I wasn't referring to a XML sitemap. Trying to add a navigation-able links to all pages through a directory.